# Mecurial merges --- Why do I supply a commit message for other user's changes?

Tags: mercurial, merge

I think I "get" most of Mecurial, but one thing that bothers me is, when I do a pull to grab changes made by others, in other files, how does it make any sense for me to have to supply a commit message? Those users already had an opportunity to supply a commit message when they pushed the corresponding changeset to "the" server.

As far as I know, there's no way to push just the part of the tree where I made my changes, so when others make a change to unrelated files in an unrelated part of the tree, and I have a changeset that needs to be pushed, I have to "pull", "merge", and then "commit", where I supply a message describing THEIR changes, changes that have already in theory been described by their commit message(s).

I'm probably not understanding something. Is there a better way to handle the situation where I:

```
 ~$ ## Make some changes
 ~$ hg ci -m 'blah'
 ~$ ## Attempt to "push" and get "abort: push creates new remote head"
 ~$ hg pull
 ~$ hg merge # <- totally unrelated files updated here
 ~$ hg ci -m "SOMEONE ELSE'S FILES CHANGED....!"
 ~$ hg push
```

??

Comment: Thanks all. Much clearer understanding now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You **must** to understand **value of merge** and your **actions on merge** better

Commit message of changeset (conventionally) is "Short description of what is done by this changeset". For mergeset "done" is "Merge changes from ..." and commit messages from second parent's branch of this mergeset will inform, that really (which changes) was merged

Comment: I guess this makes some sense. When I do a merge+commit, I'm changing my repository. It does make sense for me to provide an explanation for why my repository is changing. I can chose whether to supply a separate commit message for the merged files -vs- my changes or not. I guess I'll deal with it and let my grasp get better over time.

Comment: @CaptainMidday - when you pull, you get others changes in your repo and (with glog) can see diverged history before merge-point. And read about real changes in *commit-messages in "foreign" changesets*

Answer (score 1):

The merge is the change you're commenting on, not the changesets you pulled. So in your example:

```
~$ ## Make some changes
~$ hg ci -m 'blah'
~$ ## Attempt to "push" and get "abort: push creates new remote head"
~$ hg pull
~$ hg merge 
~$ hg ci -m "Merged with changes on the Flibble-floo server"
~$ hg push
```

Remember you could be pulling directly from other developers or from different branches. The message should describe the merge you've done.

```
~$ hg pull bob
~$ hg merge 
~$ hg ci -m "Merged with Bob's changes"
```

Comment: So tempting to +1 this answer just for the `Flibble-floo` server. Instead I'm +1'ing as it's a good answer anyway.

Comment: @icabod Do it! You *know* you want to. :evil laugh:

Answer (score 0):

It is important to understand what a [merge](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/Merge) is. Your commit is merging the two divergent branches, not committing that user's code, and thus a more suitable commit message will involve the word "merge".

Now I will show you a still better way.

In this case, where you have never pushed the code that you are trying to push, it is probably more suitable to [rebase](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/RebaseExtension). Your case is exactly covered inside that document, in [A common case](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/RebaseExtension#A_common_case).

```
~$ ## Make some changes
~$ hg ci -m 'blah'
~$ ## Attempt to "push" and get "abort: push creates new remote head"
~$ hg pull --rebase  # Or alternately, `hg pull; hg rebase`
~$ hg push
```

Then you end up with linear history, which is typically nicer to work with (when feasible).

Remember that, as noted, the extension needs to be enabled first in your [configuration](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgrc.5.html):

```
[extensions]
rebase =
```